# How can I analyze the size of my firmware image?

Tags: c++, g++, embedded, firmware

We're currently developing a firmware for an IoT product based on the popular ESP32 chip using their ESP-IDF framework, which builds the binaries using a GCC/G++-Toolchain named `xtensa` (https://github.com/icamgo/xtensa-toolchain).

Recently, I noticed that the binary size got fairly huge (just shy of 1 MB) and decided to take a look and try to reduce it. `NDEBUG` is defined, `-Os` is enabled and the output is being `strip`ped.

Basically, the toolchain produces an `.elf` file, so I took a look at its contents:

```
nm -S -C --size-sort <my-app>.elf
```

The six largest functions (6 kB-12 kB in size) are:

```
4011b24c 0000187b T __ssvfscanf_r
400f9f38 00001ffa T _svfiprintf_r
400f2aa4 000020fe T _vfiprintf_r
4012005c 000030d2 T _svfwprintf_r
400ef4d8 000030de T _svfprintf_r
400f50dc 000031e6 T _vfprintf_r
```

So, the largest functions in my firmware image are vfprintf and friends, adding up to about 60 kB of binary size alone. Why are they this big? How can I reduce their size or get rid of them (I don't need vfprintf at all since I don't have a file system on the microcontroller)?

Are there any further techniques to reduce the binary size? How would I proceed in my quest?

Edit (Clarification on the reason for the optimization):

There are different versions of the ESP32 with **up to** 16 MB of flash memory. The one we use has 4 MB. 1 MB of that is reserved for storing pinned server certificates, trusted URLs configuration options. And, since we want OTA-update functionality, we need to keep the same amount of flash memory as consumed by the application image free for a new version of it. That leaves us with 1.5 MB of flash for our application image, which is not too far away from our current 1 MB. Therefore, I think it is justified to think about size reduction before that problem stops us from introducing new features at all.

I do realize that 60 kB of unwanted vfprintf() functions is a small part of 1 MB, but we do need a lot of actually helpful libraries (mbedtls for encryption, a full IP-stack, a thin web server, ...). I cannot get rid of these, so I'd like to reduce the size *as much as possible and feasible* by removing functions I don't have any use for.

Comment: ?? So you have 12kiB of unwanted code, but your firmware is shy of 1MiB? ~990kiB just "happened" there in thousands of tiny functions, all written by you, or how should we understand it? Did you check the linking map thoroughly, what is going on? (google gave me somewhat related article actually focused on embedded, just different platform https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/900.php ) ... Techniques to reduce binary size = to have less code. For example one of first calculators did use it's own interpreter to fit into the available ROM (2kiB IIRC). Then again you have 1+Mi ... :-o

Comment: And if it is IoT, it should probably allow for security [digitally signed] patches, some recovery mode/factory reset, some hardened TCP/IP stack (probably IPv6 one), etc... then 1MiB may be not that much, I would expect more like 10-100MiB size.

Comment: You may not need `vfprintf` byt `printf` is probably implemented with it.  `printf` is a call to `fprintf` on the stdio stream which in turn is a call to `vfprintf`.  Stripping symbols reduces the size of the _object code_ not the binary.  The symbol information that strip removes is used only by the development host debugger and is not part of the binary image.  You should instruct the linker to output a map file rather then reverse engineering the .elf file.  If your image is truly 1Mb, then the 60kb is 6% - is that really your problem; what about data constants or initialisers?

Comment: ESP32 has 16Mb of flash memory; perhaps you are worrying about this prematurely?

Comment: @old_timer : Resource limited!?  I dream of 16Mb!

Comment: This nm fragment appears to include both full and integer-only versions of the printf family, which seems odd to start with.  Also apparently wide-character versions too. Something is wrong with this picture.  Also blaming the library functions like it couldn't possibly be the application design or implementation, is probably denying Occam's Razor.

Comment: @Clifford I am not blaming the library functions only, I just took a look at the list of largest function in my code and found the vfprintf variants there. I wouldn't call that an unreasonable course of action. It is true that we also have our own application code and that contributes to the overall size, but according to the output I'm seeing, the largest part of the binary size stems from libraries.

Comment: By the way, why the downvotes? Is it unwanted on StackOverflow to ask about how I can find out how functions I have no use for got into my binary?
Or was the wording of the question unfit?

Comment: But it is _your_ code that either directly or indirectly causes the libraries to be linked.

Comment: @Clifford Yes, you're absolutely right. That is why I'm asking how I can get rid of them. How can I find out where exactly I reference these functions indirectly (I definitely do not call them directly)?

Comment: @Oromis : Response to your last comment has been added to my answer.

Comment: You could also use `objdump` and `readelf` (or their cross-`xtensa` variants) to inspect your ELF executable

Answer (score 4):

Considering the size of individual functions is not a sound approach.  A single "tiny" function may have hundreds of equally tiny dependencies in its call graph which on aggregate constitute a huge chunk.  For example for the following:

```
int main()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        do_statemachine() ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

`main()` will be tiny but ultimately causes *all* the rest of the application be linked because of whatever `do_statemachine()` does, which could be *any size*.  You need to consider the total size of a function and *all* its dependencies.

Also the total size of static or constant data initialisers, also be stored in ROM needs consideration too.

You should use the linker to generate map file and call graph - that is likley to be more useful than using nm after the event.

With respect to the specific symbols in your question, you have to ask yourself what are you calling in stdio?  For example `printf` needs stream access (for `stdout`), format specifier parsing and variadic argument traversal - that is *all* provided by `vfprintf`.  If that were not so you'd have duplicated code, and while you might link fewer functions, they'd all be *very* large and potentially exhibit different behaviour. The fact that you have "file" oriented functions in the link is not an issue specifically; stdio operates on stream rather than files - "file" is conceptual, not physical.  If you have not hooked your library into a file system (or if one is not provided in the tools already) no filesystem code will be included.  The low-level stream access is performed by low-level I/O functions that may or may not support file access.

Another possibility is that the library lacks granularity - if all these functions were defined in the same object module, the linker will have no choice but to link them all even if they are not referenced.  That might explain why you have integer, floating point and wide-character versions in the link.

Comment: I would also add that printf and its friends tend to be very large if they support full standards compliance. Sometimes, development environments offer lower functionality for smaller size. But printf can intrude in insidious  ways, such as using the ASSERT macro. I usually find myself in a constant hunt through the linker map looking for dependencies on standard library functions that I do not want. Welcome to our world.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I do have a `.map` file, but as far as I know, it only contains a mapping "function name" => "object file it comes from". Do I miss something here?

How would I generate a call graph? I tried the `radare2` tool as suggested [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16081/how-to-generate-the-call-graph-of-a-binary), but I haven't found a program yet that can open the resulting dot file. They all fail due to an out-of-memory error (the dot file is just about 2.8 MB in size)

Comment: I see your point about `printf()` being based on `vfprintf()`, that makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps the GNU linker will not do that for you (I don't currently use GCC), and third-party tools may work at the source level and not drill into object libraries.  No doubt the source for your C library is available however (https://github.com/jcmvbkbc/newlib-xtensa)?  Note that elf file size is not teh same as binary size.

Comment: Your last paragraph is traditionally correct. However, link-time optimization (LTO) makes it not necessarily true.

Answer (score 2):

Where those symbols came there are more wchar related symbols that you dont need.
You can get rid of those symbols by building the ESP32 toolchain with

```
-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections
```

enabled for newlib. Also set the flag `--disable-wchar_t` on libstdc++. Then use `-Wl,--gc-sections` to get rid of those sections.

You can also try to use `-flto` it should do the same for you - but I ran into issues when building newlib and libstdc++ with lto. It seems that the build tooling of libstdc++ has issues with the newlib archives then.
Nonetheless lto is what you should prefer when possible, as it also nicely detects and ODR violations or other broken code that a unit-by-unit compilation might hide.